# Find outliers to each band of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The goal is to find extremely small or large records for each band based on a formula.

Input:

```
Distance Rate
10       5
25       200
50       300
1000     5
2000     2000
```

Bands are defined by my input. For example, I want to have two bands for this input (actually there are more, like 10 bands) for distance: 1-100, 101-10000.

For each band, we want to find all records that the rates are outliers by formula `f` (two standard deviations away from mean, if you are interested in the formula)

The formula `f` I want to use

`(Rate- avg(Rate) over ()) / (stddev(Rate) over ()) > 2`

Output:

```
Distance Rate
10       5
1000     5 (this number is for illustrative purpose only.)
```

The difficult part is I do not know how to do it for each band, and it makes applying formula more difficult.

Comment: What is a "band of records"?  And what part of the problem is an issue?  A sample query would really help.  How do you assign the bands, for instance?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  I interpret it as a group of rows with a certain column's value fitting within an arbitrary range.

Comment: @TabAlleman Yes. Let me put more explanations in the question.

Comment: What is your desired output if there is more than one outlier in a band?

Comment: @TabAlleman I want them all, as long as they meet the requirements of formula `f`.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how you intend to apply your formula (my guess would be UDF), you can create your "bands" by grouping by a CASE expression:

```
GROUP BY CASE
  WHEN Distance BETWEEN 1 AND 100 THEN 'Band1'
  WHEN Distance BETWEEN 101 AND 10000 THEN 'Band2'
  ETC
END
```

Similarly you use the same CASE expression in a RANK() OVER () function, if that works better for the rest of your query.

EDIT:   based on your clarification, you need to handle this with a correlated sub-query in your WHERE clause.  I would consider encapsulating it in a UDF to make the main query look cleaner.  Something like:

```
WHERE (Rate- {Correlated query to select the AVG(rate) of all rows in this band (using the above CASE statement to determine "this band"} over ()) / (stddev(Rate) over ()) > 2
```

Comment: I have add more information on the formula. Could you take a look?